# Regex match one character one time in any combination

Tags: java, regex

Read much questions and answers but got no idea how to solve my problem.

I have a String something like this:

`23424(223)+32 -32`

allowed in the full String is:

- any `number` multiple times anywhere of the String
- one time `)` anywhere of the String
- one time `(` anywhere of the String
- one time `+` anywhere of the String
- multiple times `spaces` anywhere of the String
- multiple times `-` anywhere of the String

For me the most problem is to find the one time character anywhere of the String. Hope you can help me.

This example String should not match. `23424(223)3+3)2 -32`

Comment: Would the people who downvoted this please explain why they did?

Comment: What have you tried so far? From your question, `)3(+` is also valid, right? If not, please provide more examples, and a clearer description of your specific question. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), also you could read again [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MartinNyolt I tried many combinations. Wont post them all. But the thing where I struggle is the combination of all rules. At the end the one timer anywhere of the String. And yes ')3(' is allowed

Comment: Do you *have* to use a regex? A simple linear scanning of the string would be probably easier for you to implement.

Comment: @MartinNyolt No I dont have. Just thought there is a "simple" regex solution to have it in a one liner. Sure I can do it java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with negative lookaheads:

```
^(?!.*\(.*\()(?!.*\).*\))(?!.*\+.*\+)[\d ()+-]+$
```

We are using 3 negative lookaheads:

```
(?!.*\(.*\()  # Negative lookahead to disallow more than one (
(?!.*\).*\))  # Negative lookahead to disallow more than one )
(?!.*\+.*\+)  # Negative lookahead to disallow more than one +
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xy0nWq/1)

**Reference:** [Lookarounds in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

In Java use:

```
String regex = "^(?!.*\\(.*\\()(?!.*\\).*\\))(?!.*\\+.*\\+)[\\d ()+-]+$";
```

Comment: This also matches `3`, which contains neither `(`, `)`, nor `+`.

Comment: Yes, this regex allows 0 or one `(`, `)` or `+`. That's what I interpreted from the question.

Comment: Three downvotes for this soultion is perfectly fine ;) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it without regex , just iterate over the string , and put each character in a map with this logic

```
        if(map.get(str.charAt(i)) == null)
              map.put(str.charAt(i),1)
         else 
              map.put(str.charAt(i),map.get(str.charAt(i))+1)
```

when done with the loop, check each one time character in the map and see which one has more than one occurrence